# Formato de Fecha en columna para exportar en Excel C#

Tags: c#, excel

Trato de exportar un `datatable` a Excel pero en algunas columnas de fecha me las exporta en número, ya intenté enviando desde la base de datos la información que necesito pero no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas seguro que el problema no es en excel, que no entiende la fecha como una fecha y hace la cuenta? probaste en excel cambiar el tipo de campo?

Comment: bro, ya miraste el formato de la fecha que estas enviando desde el php o la bd ?

Comment: El número 43102 representa el 1/02/2018, es esa la fecha que buscas? Solo tienes que darle formato de fecha a la columna

Comment: hola, si hago el cambio de formato en excel funciona y muestra el dato correcto, o como se debe ver, el objetivo es que cuando  exporte la información desde la aplicación salga  esa columna en formato fecha

Comment: La información sale en formato fecha. El problema es de excel, no de la información.

Comment: el detalle esta entre  al momento de exportar, si verifico el datatable aparece la fecha , pero al salir a excel sale en numero

Comment: ya intentaste convertirlo a tipo string antes de exportarlo? creo que esa es tu solución

Answer (score 0):

Antes de exportar, hazle un cambio al tipo de dato de la columna, mejor si la llevas a un Varchar y al momento de exportarlo al excel lo tomara como Varchar

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR,fecha, 10) AS FECHA FROM TABLA
```